# editing a specific line in python 3.5.1

Tags: python

Having trouble with overwriting a specific line in python 3.5.1 I know there are solutions out there but they use external modules or are lengthy and specific to that persons problem.

is there a line of code that could do that?
here is what im looking for:  File.write("insert text here","line to overwrite")

here is my code:

```
from time import sleep
import os
#functions
def pause():
    pause = input("Paused press <ENTER> to continue")
print("attempting to open workspace......")
#

Fo = open("work1.txt", 'r+')#opens the file
print("workspace opened")
#mainloop :D
def Mainloop():
    global Fo
    Fo.close()
    Fo = open("work1.txt", 'r+')
    os.system('cls')
    print('''

''')
    print ("   ======")
    print ("   Read")
    print ("   Write")
    print ("   ======")
    print("")
    INP = input('   >')
    if INP == "Read":
        Hm = input("how much?")
        print("")
        if Hm == 'All':
            print(Fo.read())
        else:
            print(Fo.read(int(Hm)))
        sleep(2)
        pause()
        os.system('cls')
        Mainloop()
    if INP == "Write":
        TextToAdd = input("Text to Write:   ")
        Fo.write(TextToAdd)
        os.system('cls')
        Mainloop()
    else:
        print('Not avaliable')
        sleep(2)
        os.system('cls')
        Mainloop()

Mainloop()
pause()
```

Comment: Is that code actually relevant to the question? In general, you cannot *"edit a specific line"*, the easiest thing is to read in the file, alter it in memory and write it back out again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to replace a single line in the textfile with a different line?

```
    for line in open(filename):
        if line.rstrip('\n') == search_pattern:
            sys.stdout.write('%s\n' % replacement)
        else:
            sys.stdout.write('%s' % line)
```

Instead of the `sys.stdout.write()`, you could e.g. populate a list, or write into a (temporary) file, etc.

The important idea is to first get the required input (search pattern, replacement string), and then iterate over the file line by line.

Solution properties:

- low memory usage (as you only keep a single line in memory)
- O(n) runtime - the more lines the file has, the longer this approach takes

Alternatively, if the file is guaranteed to be small, you can read the contents into a string and use `str.replace()` to replace the line you are searching for.